# How to retrieve item list from html table with xpath?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to extract table information into a dictionary within python 3.7.

The html from the table looks like this:

```
            <dl class="rlxr-specs__block-list">
                <dt class="rlxr-specs__block-list--name">heading</dt>
                <dd class="rlxr-specs__definition-content">
                    <div class="rlxr-specs__definition-title">Key1</div>
                    <span class="rlxr-specs__definition-desc">bla</span>
                </dd>
                <dd class="rlxr-specs__definition-content">
                    <div class="rlxr-specs__definition-title">Key2</div>
                    <span class="rlxr-specs__definition-desc">blub</span>
                </dd>
```

My best guess is:

```
items{}
for row in response.xpath('//dd[@class="rlxr-specs__definition-content"]'):
    items[row.xpath('./div/text()').extract_first()] = items[row.xpath('./span/text()').extract_first()]
```

I am getting a Keyerror, with a key from another part of the page. So something within the xpath selector must be wrong.

More info:

```
>>> for row in response.xpath('//dd[@class="rlxr-specs__definition-content"]'):
...     print(row.xpath('./div/text()'))
... 
[<Selector xpath='./div/text()' data='Gehäuse'>]
[<Selector xpath='./div/text()' data='Aufbau des Oyster Gehäuses'>]
[<Selector xpath='./div/text()' data='Durchmesser'>]
[<Selector xpath='./div/text()' data='Material'>]
[<Selector xpath='./div/text()' data='Lünette'>]
[<Selector xpath='./div/text()' data='Aufzugskrone'>]
[<Selector xpath='./div/text()' data='Uhrglas'>]
[<Selector xpath='./div/text()' data='Wasserdichtheit'>]
[<Selector xpath='./div/text()' data='Manufakturwerk'>]
[<Selector xpath='./div/text()' data='Kaliber'>]
[<Selector xpath='./div/text()' data='Ganggenauigkeit'>]
[<Selector xpath='./div/text()' data='Funktionen'>]
[<Selector xpath='./div/text()' data='Oszillator'>]
[<Selector xpath='./div/text()' data='Aufzug'>]
[<Selector xpath='./div/text()' data='Gangreserve'>]
[<Selector xpath='./div/text()' data='Armband'>]
[<Selector xpath='./div/text()' data='Material'>]
[<Selector xpath='./div/text()' data='Schließe'>]
[<Selector xpath='./div/text()' data='Zifferblatt'>]
[<Selector xpath='./div/text()' data='Edelsteinfassung'>]
[]
>>> for row in response.xpath('//dd[@class="rlxr-specs__definition-content"]'):
...     print(row.xpath('./span/text()'))
... 
[<Selector xpath='./span/text()' data='Oyster, 28 mm, Edelstahl Oystersteel und'>]
[<Selector xpath='./span/text()' data='Monoblock-Mittelteil, verschraubter Gehä'>]
[<Selector xpath='./span/text()' data='28 mm'>]
[<Selector xpath='./span/text()' data='Rolesor Everose (Kombination aus Edelsta'>]
[<Selector xpath='./span/text()' data='Diamantlünette'>]
[<Selector xpath='./span/text()' data='Verschraubbare Twinlock-Aufzugskrone mit'>]
[<Selector xpath='./span/text()' data='Kratzfestes Saphirglas, Zykloplupe\xa0zur\xa0V'>]
[<Selector xpath='./span/text()' data='Bis 100 Meter Tiefe wasserdicht'>]
[<Selector xpath='./span/text()' data='Mechanisches Perpetual-Uhrwerk, Selbstau'>]
[<Selector xpath='./span/text()' data='2236, Rolex Manufakturwerk'>]
[<Selector xpath='./span/text()' data='-2/+2 Sekunden pro Tag, gemessen nach de'>]
[<Selector xpath='./span/text()' data='Stunden-, Minuten- und Sekundenzeiger im'>]
[]
[<Selector xpath='./span/text()' data='Selbstaufzugsmechanismus, in beide Richt'>]
[<Selector xpath='./span/text()' data='Circa 55 Stunden'>]
[<Selector xpath='./span/text()' data='Jubilé, fünfreihig'>]
[<Selector xpath='./span/text()' data='Rolesor Everose (Kombination aus Edelsta'>]
[<Selector xpath='./span/text()' data='Verdeckte Crownclasp-Faltschließe'>]
[<Selector xpath='./span/text()' data='Helles Perlmuttzifferblatt mit Diamanten'>]
[<Selector xpath='./span/text()' data='Diamanten, Fassung 18 Karat Gold'>]
[<Selector xpath='./span/text()' data='Chronometer der Superlative  (COSC + Rol'>]
>>>
```

How can I pull the table into the dict?

Comment: Replace with `items[row.xpath('./div/text()')[0]] = row.xpath('./span/text()')[0]`

Comment: I do get a IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: *" IndexError"*: **One** of the `xpath(...` returns a **empyt** list. [Edit] your Question and show the **first** output of `print(row.xpath('./div/text()'))` and `print(row.xpath('./span/text()'))`

Comment: you are right, there seem to be empty elements. Edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check whether there is a title and description values or not and if there is no value - set default value:

```
items{}
for row in response.xpath('//dd[@class="rlxr-specs__definition-content"]'):
    title = row.xpath('./div/text()').extract_first() or "No title"
    description = row.xpath('./span/text()').extract_first() or "No description"
    items[title] = description
```